# How do I add a user when I'm using Alpine as a base image?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm using `alpine` (or an image that is based on Alpine) as the base image in my Dockerfile. Which instructions do I need to add to create a user?

Eventually I'll use this user to run the application I'll place into the container so that the root user does not.

Answer (score 468, accepted):

Alpine uses the command `adduser` and `addgroup` for creating users and groups (rather than `useradd` and `usergroup`).

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Create a group and user
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup

# Tell docker that all future commands should run as the appuser user
USER appuser
```

The flags for `adduser` are:

```
Usage: adduser [OPTIONS] USER [GROUP]

Create new user, or add USER to GROUP

        -h DIR          Home directory
        -g GECOS        GECOS field
        -s SHELL        Login shell
        -G GRP          Group
        -S              Create a system user
        -D              Don't assign a password
        -H              Don't create home directory
        -u UID          User id
        -k SKEL         Skeleton directory (/etc/skel)
```

[Add new user official docs](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_new_user)

Comment: Or alternatively, you can replace the whole snippet above using this: ```USER 405``` which is the guest user within Alpine Linux.

Comment: Why not `USER guest`?

Comment: I'd go with creating a new user because I want that user to have the same UID/GID as the one on the host OS, so that there's no permission issue when running docker in Linux. (not an issue with macOS/Windows users)

Comment: Note that since Alpine is based on BusyBox, its `adduser` and `addgroup` commands are different from `adduser` and `addgroup` as provided by Debian and Ubuntu which in turn are front ends to `useradd` and `groupadd`. Notably, the Debian and Ubuntu commands only support long form options. See: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/adduser/adduser.8.en.html

Comment: I've already created a docker container, now what command do I need to run to add a user?

Comment: Or Alternatively, you can use https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/issues/102#issuecomment-404637485

Comment: Why are these short hand flags not documented in the official docs? edit: apparently this command is added by busybox: https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

Comment: What's a "system" user?

Answer (score 159):

The commands are `adduser` and `addgroup`.

Here's a template for Docker you can use in busybox environments (alpine) as well as Debian-based environments (Ubuntu, etc.):

```
ENV USER=docker
ENV GROUPNAME=$USER
ENV UID=12345
ENV GID=23456

RUN addgroup \
    --gid "$GID" \
    "$GROUPNAME" \
&&  adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "$(pwd)" \
    --ingroup "$GROUPNAME" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "$UID" \
    $USER
```

Note the following:

- `--disabled-password` prevents prompt for a password
- `--gecos ""` circumvents the prompt for "Full Name" etc. on Debian-based systems
- `--home "$(pwd)"` sets the user's home to the WORKDIR. ***You may not want this.***
- `--no-create-home` prevents cruft getting copied into the directory from `/etc/skel`

The usage description for these applications is **missing the long flags** present in the code for [adduser](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/loginutils/adduser.c) and [addgroup](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/loginutils/addgroup.c).

The following long-form flags should work both in alpine as well as debian-derivatives:

### adduser

```
BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-05-30 10:45:57 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: adduser [OPTIONS] USER [GROUP]

Create new user, or add USER to GROUP

        --home DIR           Home directory
        --gecos GECOS        GECOS field
        --shell SHELL        Login shell
        --ingroup GRP        Group (by name)
        --system             Create a system user
        --disabled-password  Don't assign a password
        --no-create-home     Don't create home directory
        --uid UID            User id
```

One thing to note is that if `--ingroup` isn't set then the GID is assigned to match the UID. If the GID corresponding to the provided UID already exists adduser will fail.

### addgroup

```
BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-05-30 10:45:57 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: addgroup [-g GID] [-S] [USER] GROUP

Add a group or add a user to a group

        --gid GID  Group id
        --system   Create a system group
```

I discovered all of this while trying to write my own alternative to the [fixuid](https://github.com/boxboat/fixuid) project for running containers as the hosts UID/GID.

[My entrypoint helper script](https://github.com/Rexypoo/docker-entrypoint-helper) can be found on GitHub.

The intent is to prepend that script as the first argument to `ENTRYPOINT` which should cause Docker to infer UID and GID from a relevant bind mount.

An environment variable "TEMPLATE" may be required to determine where the permissions should be inferred from.

(At the time of writing I don't have documentation for my script. It's still on the todo list!!)

Comment: +1, using long form for command args increases readability and makes maintenance easier. When writing shell scripts always use the long form (Dockerfile RUN *is* nothing else than a shell script).

Comment: Great answer, and thank for sharing your script. I am interested in retaining the host uid/gid: on debian based images my approach consisted in passing these over through env variables or infer from a bound  workspace folder. All this was made easier by using commands `useradd/groupadd` with the `--non-unique` flag. Is there anyway to create duplicate id users/groups in alpine?

Comment: I found an answer to my question: installing `shadow`.

Comment: Using this in an entrypoint is probably not sufficient, because you start the container as root. What stops the user from exiting back to root?

Comment: Isn't `--ingroup "$USER"` supposed to be `--ingroup "$GID"`? I'm confused.

Comment: Is `RUN adduser` even necessary? Why don't we just use `USER 10001:10001` in the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @Thegerdfather you're right. Without that, the build will fail (and `$GID` would be useless). The group needs to exist already, too

Comment: @Thegerdfather as it turns out I edited my post and left that part of the code a bit unclear. The flag `--ingroup` specifies a group by name. The flag `--gid` is intended for specifying a group number. In both cases the group must already exist. In the short term I'll update my answer with a `GROUPNAME`. A clearer answer would also include `addgroup` however my original answer failed to run.

Comment: @TBG `--ingroup` accepts a group name only, it will fail if you use a GID. As Alpine's Busybox `adduser` command does not support the `--gid` option, `--ingroup` is the _only_ way to configure the default group across platforms as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 16):

There is package `shadow` that brings `useradd` & `usermod`.

`adduser` has some stupid limitations:

```
$ sudo adduser --disabled-password root
adduser: user 'root' in use
```

but `usermod` doesn't:

```
$ sudo apk add shadow
$ sudo usermod --unlock root
```

Comment: shadow also includes groupadd too and makes alpine consistent in this regard with other distros so if you have a multi distro script (e.g. docker) using these then just install shadow when spinning up an alpine container and your script will work anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

**Group and User Setup:**

Create default values for User ID (UID), Group ID (GID), and username, which can be customized using arguments.

```
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG GROUP_GID=1000
ARG UGNAME=webapp
```

**Remove Existing Group and User:**

Check for the presence of an existing group and user. If either exists, remove them.

```
RUN if getent passwd ${USER_UID} >/dev/null; then \
    deluser $(getent passwd ${USER_UID} | cut -d: -f1); fi

RUN if getent group ${GROUP_GID} >/dev/null; then \
    delgroup $(getent group ${GROUP_GID} | cut -d: -f1); fi
```

**Create New Group and User:**

Create a new system group and a new system user with the specified UID, GID, and username.

```
RUN addgroup --system --gid ${GROUP_GID} ${UGNAME}

RUN adduser --system --disabled-password --home /home/${UGNAME} \
    --uid ${USER_UID} --ingroup ${UGNAME} ${UGNAME}
```

Set the user as the default user for the container. All subsequent commands will run with this user.

```
USER ${UGNAME}
```