# Permission denied inside Docker container on shared directory

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm new to Docker so I might not have some of the terminology correct. Inside the container I'm getting a permission denied error on a directory shared with the host. They appear to have matching uid:gid and the permissions host side are 777. The container is not for running in the background.

I'm using the container to run a big series of untrusted programs one at a time each needing the same initial conditions. So I don't think it's feasible to copy stuff into the docker image at build time. I felt the optimal thing to do is copy the programs one at a time to a temp directory on the host and then share that directory with the fresh container for each run. I also need to collect the output from the container-run programs and keep them on the host so I can see how each program's output differs from the others.

I have looked at the following questions/answers:

- [Docker: Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)
- [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue) - successfully used to make docker run as someone other than root
- [How do I add a user when I'm using Alpine as a base image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955097/how-do-i-add-a-user-when-im-using-alpine-as-a-base-image) and [Setting up a new user](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_new_user) - used to create the user and group

I am:

- running docker as an ordinary user uid 1000, gid 1000, also belonging to the group `docker`
- setting permissions on the shared directory host side to be 777 with uid:gid as `1000:1000` which is the same as the user
- setting the uid and gid inside the container to match uid and gid from the host
- using the Dockerfile to create a uid and gid each of `1000`

I read [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host) that `If the first argument begins with a / or ~/, you’re creating a bindmount. Remove that, and you’re naming the volume.` So I tried both. The bindmount version seems to have the correct uid:gid but is permission denied, the volume version comes out as `root:root`.

As a newbie it's hard to know what information to share so here's everything I think might be useful:

#### Docker command attempt 1

```
[osboxes@osboxes tmp]$ pwd
/var/tmp
osboxes@osboxes tmp]$ whoami
osboxes
[osboxes@osboxes tmp]$ grep osboxes /etc/passwd
osboxes:x:1000:1000:osboxes.org:/home/osboxes:/bin/bash
[osboxes@osboxes tmp]$ groups
osboxes wheel vboxsf docker
[osboxes@osboxes tmp]$ grep osboxes /etc/group
wheel:x:10:osboxes
osboxes:x:1000:osboxes
vboxsf:x:981:osboxes
docker:x:1001:osboxes

[osboxes@osboxes tmp]$ ls -al
total 2
drwxrwxrwt. 11 root    root    4096 Dec 31 12:13 .
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root    root    4096 Jul  5 05:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 abrt    abrt       6 Jul  5 05:00 abrt
drwxrwxrwx.  2 osboxes osboxes    6 Dec 31 12:13 host
```

continues...

```
[osboxes@osboxes tmp]$ docker run --rm -v /var/tmp/host:/var/tmp/container:rw \
--user appuser:appgroup --workdir /var/tmp/container \
-it alpine_bash_jdk11 /bin/bash
bash-5.0$ pwd
/var/tmp/container
bash-5.0$ ls -al
ls: can't open '.': Permission denied
total 0
bash-5.0$ ls -al ..
total 0
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root            23 Dec 31 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            17 Dec 16 10:31 ..
drwxrwxrwx    2 appuser  appgroup         6 Dec 31 12:13 container
bash-5.0$ whoami
appuser
bash-5.0$ groups
appgroup
bash-5.0$ grep appuser /etc/passwd
appuser:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/appuser:/sbin/nologin
bash-5.0$ grep appuser /etc/group
appgroup:x:1000:appuser
```

#### Docker command attempt 2

```
everything as before except
for removing the qualified path to the host's
/var/tmp/host directory

docker run --rm -v host:/var/tmp/container:rw \
--user appuser:appgroup --workdir /var/tmp/container \
-it alpine_bash_jdk11 /bin/bash

bash-5.0$ pwd
/var/tmp/container
bash-5.0$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             6 Dec 31 12:13 .
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root            23 Dec 31 13:03 ..
bash-5.0$ ls -al ..
total 0
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root            23 Dec 31 13:03 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            17 Dec 16 10:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             6 Dec 31 12:13 container
bash-5.0$ whoami
appuser
bash-5.0$ groups
appgroup
bash-5.0$ echo hello from contanier > container.msg.txt
bash: container.msg.txt: Permission denied
```

#### Docker build command

```
as user osboxes
docker build -t alpine_bash_jdk11 .
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache update
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community

ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm"
ENV PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup -u 1000
USER appuser
```

**I haven't used docker compose because I'm still getting my head round basic docker.**

#### Virtual Machine which is the Docker Host

```
CentOS 7.2003 from osboxes.org, organization's decision, not mine
Linux osboxes 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 18 16:34:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I did a yum update, then yum installed all the stuff needed to install VirtualBox guest additions which is working ok
Docker version 1.13.1, build 0be3e21/1.13.1
```

#### Physical Host

```
Windows 10 64-bit
VirtualBox 6.1.4r136177
both these are the organization's decisions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr: had old version of docker due to wrong install command

**The answer:** install `docker-ce` instead of `docker`. Depending on your system that might be

`sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce`

or

`sudo yum -y install docker-ce`

instead of `sudo apt-get install -y docker`

or

`sudo yum -y install docker`

Solution: update docker

Having found [this article](https://www.openlogic.com/blog/install-docker-centos) I could see that I had the wrong version of docker. I justifiably thought the correct command was

```
sudo yum install -y docker
```

but it should have been `docker-ce`

I had to `yum erase -y docker docker-common`

Now I have `Docker version 20.10.1, build 831ebea`