# Why am I getting an error of UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition after creating a user and using it for my alpine image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The error I'm getting:

`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition`

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.1-alpine
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -D -S appuser -G appgroup
USER appuser
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I started getting this error when I implemented this in my deployment.yaml:

```
 securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1212
```

I tried to follow this other answer: [How do I add a user when I'm using Alpine as a base image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955097/how-do-i-add-a-user-when-im-using-alpine-as-a-base-image)

With the code provided am I not giving a user for the image?

Comment: Any interruption that occurred during your Helm install/upgrade process could lead you to a state where you cannot install another release anymore. In the release logs the UPGRADE FAILED will show as an error.<br>

Comment: These 2 pointers will give you a place to start. 1. Roll back to the previous working version using the **helm rollback** command. 2. Delete the **helm secret** associated with the release and re-run the upgrade command. Refer to OPS community [article](https://community.ops.io/the_cozma/k8s-fix-helm-release-failing-with-an-upgrade-still-in-progress-4660) & [Github open issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4558) open since 2018, which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello@GustaMan9000, the above comment helped you to resolve your issue?